# Use jar from a local repository when building an executable jar

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on a multi-module springboot-app that looks like this :

```
basedir
 module - pom.xml 
 module2 - pom.xml
 module3 - pom.xml         <---- this project contains the Main class
pom.xml (parent pom)
```

and I've  got a `library.jar` that can't be placed into our nexus for various reasons. So I've installed into to a project-local repository following with `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/myjar.jar -DgroupId=id.group -DartifactId=myjar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=${project.basedir}/lib`

I've added both dependency and repository into parent pom , because all 3 modules use this jar

```
...
  <dependency>
     <artifactId>myjar</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <groupId>id.group</group>
  </dependency>
...

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>lib</id>
    <url>file:///${project.basedir}/lib
  <repository>
</repositories>
```

But still, the the dependency is not being found, neither by IntelliJ nor when i try to create a JAR. When i do `mvn clean install` it ignores the local repositry and tries to download it from the nexus. Could it be my company `setting.xml` config that is at fault or is it the multi-module setup?

Answer (score 0):

Your supplied sample seems faulty (the URL tag is not closed) - you could try to install your maven dependency locally as you did and then use the maven offline switch and see if it works

```
mvn -o install
```

Comment: the tag is closed in pom.xml. I've tried installing it online before but it not working